# Linqpad returns very elaborate SQL query when converting from LINQ

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I wrote LINQ query using LinqPad to return users that should retrieve an invitation for a questionnaire. The query runs fine and returns the correct results.

However I need this query in SQL form. When I click on the SQL button in LinqPad it returns the SQL form but with a separate select statement for each individual record. Leaving me with an SQL query of 2000 lines.

This is my LINQ query

```
var result2 = AI_Conversations
.Where(f => f.End_DateTime.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date).GroupBy(f => f.Email)
.Where(f => f.GroupBy(z => z.Chatbot_Name).Count() == 1)
.ToList().Select(f =>
new
{
    Name = f.LastOrDefault().Disp_Name,
    f.LastOrDefault().Email,
    Reference = f.LastOrDefault().Report_ConvNumber
});

result2.Dump();
```

Which in SQL returns the following

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2017-06-07 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[Email] AS [Key]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Email]
    FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t0]
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[End_DateTime]) = @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[Email]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t2]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t2].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t2].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
        GROUP BY [t2].[Chatbot_Name]
        ) AS [t3]
    )) = @p1
GO
```

And after the above statement another select statement is appended for each record returned by the linq query. (>200 times)

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2017-06-07 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @x1 VarChar(1000) = '(CENSORED)'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[rownames] AS [Rownames], [t0].[Report_ConvNumber], [t0].[Email], [t0].[AD_Num], [t0].[Disp_Name], [t0].[Start_DateTime], [t0].[End_DateTime], [t0].[NumOfMessages], [t0].[Duration], [t0].[Chatbot_Name], [t0].[feedback_score] AS [Feedback_score]
FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t0]
WHERE (((@x1 IS NULL) AND ([t0].[Email] IS NULL)) OR ((@x1 IS NOT NULL) AND ([t0].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND (@x1 = [t0].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
GO
```

I would expect the SQL query returned to look similar to this

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = DATEADD(dd, -1, cast(Getdate() as date))
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t1].[Email],
       [t1].[Disp_Name] AS Name,
       [t1].[Report_ConvNumber] AS Reference
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Email],
           [t0].[Disp_Name],
           [t0].[Report_ConvNumber]
    FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t0]
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[Start_DateTime]) = @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[Email],
             [t0].[Disp_Name],
             [t0].[Report_ConvNumber]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t2]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t2].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t2].[Start_DateTime]) = @p0)
        GROUP BY [t2].[Chatbot_Name]
        ) AS [t3]
    )) = @p1
GO
```

Is anyone able to tell me why LinqPad is returning such a verbose SQL query? 
How can I adjust the LINQ Query to return a 'simple' SQL query like my provided expectations?

It's an MSSQL 2014 server using Linqpad 5 if that matters

Edit:

After removing the .ToList() as Sgtmoore suggested I got the following SQL output which is more or less to my expectations.

```
    -- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 DateTime = '2017-05-04 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT (
    SELECT [t5].[AD_Num]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t4].[AD_Num]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t4]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t4].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t4].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t4].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t4].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
        ) AS [t5]
    ) AS [Name], (
    SELECT [t7].[Email]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t6].[Email]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t6]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t6].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t6].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t6].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t6].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
        ) AS [t7]
    ) AS [Email], (
    SELECT [t9].[Report_ConvNumber]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t8].[Report_ConvNumber]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t8]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t8].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t8].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t8].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t8].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
        ) AS [t9]
    ) AS [Reference]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[Email]
    FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t0]
    WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[End_DateTime]) = @p0
    GROUP BY [t0].[Email]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ((
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM (
        SELECT NULL AS [EMPTY]
        FROM [AI_Conversations] AS [t2]
        WHERE ((([t1].[Email] IS NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NULL)) OR (([t1].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t2].[Email] IS NOT NULL) AND ([t1].[Email] = [t2].[Email]))) AND (CONVERT(DATE, [t2].[End_DateTime]) = @p0)
        GROUP BY [t2].[Chatbot_Name]
        ) AS [t3]
    )) = @p1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue is the `.ToList()` in the middle is the query. However if you remove that, the query will fail as Linq2Sql does not support LastOrDefault.

So I think you would need to use `.FirstOrDefault()` and if necessary reverse the sort order.

This produces simpler TSQL, but still isn't anything like your **expected** output. From that, it would look like you want to group by Email, Reference and Report_ConvNumber, ie something like

```
var result2 = AI_Conversations
  .Where(f => f.End_DateTime.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date)
  .GroupBy(f => new {f.Email, f.Reference, f.Report_ConvNumber)
  .Where(f => f.GroupBy(z => z.Chatbot_Name).Count() == 1)
  .Select(f => new
     {
     Name = f.Key.Disp_Name,
     f.Key.Email,
     Reference = f.KeyReport_ConvNumber
   });

 result2.Dump();
```

Comment: Sgmoore, it was indeed the ToList()! My expected output was a rough draft/example. The TSQL returned by LinqPad after removing the Tolist works. Thanks a ton! I edited my original question to show the SQL it now returns.